# How do I retrieve the inputted stuff from firebase onto a vue list

Tags: javascript, vue.js, firebase-realtime-database

```
    <template>
  <div class="hello">
    <div class="heading">

    </div>
    <div class="row">
       <div class="input-field col s6">
         <div class="row">
             <div class="input-field col s6 offset-s9">
               <input v-model="blogs.Title" id="first_name" type="text" class="validate" placeholder="Title">
               <input v-model="blogs.Name" id="first_name" type="text" class="validate" placeholder="Name">
             </div>
             <div class="input-field col offset-s6  s12">
                <textarea v-model="blogs.content" id="textarea1" type="text" class="materialize-textarea s12" placeholder="Content of the blog" />
                <a class="btn" @click.prevent="post">button</a>
             </div>
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
     <div class="blog">
       <h1>{{blogs.Title}}  </h1>
       <h5 v-if="!blogs.Name =='' ">by</h5>
       <h2 >{{blogs.Name}}</h2>
       <h4 > {{blogs.content}}</h4>
     </div>
     <div class="blogposts">
       <h1>Other posts and stories</h1>
       <ul>
         <li></li>
       </ul>
     </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: 'Main',
  data(){
    return{
      blogs:{
        Name:'',
        Title:'',
        content:''
      },
      blog:[{
      }],
      realBlogs:[{
      }]
    }
  },
  methods:{
    post: function () {
        this.blog.push(this.blogs)
        this.$http.post('firebase',this.blog).then(function(data){
          console.log(data.json());
        },
         this.blog = [{}]
       );
     }
   },
   created(){
     this.$http.get('https://wbhspost-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/posts.json').then(function(data){
       return data.json();
     }).then(function(data){
       var blogsArray = [];
       for (let key in data){
         data[key].id = key
         blogsArray.push(data[key]);
       }
       this.realBlogs = blogsArray;
     })
   }

}
</script>
```

Its like a blog. it just doesnt work.
This is all my code. Its all working fine besides retrieving data.
I am using firebase for the database and its good i just have no idea on how to retrieve the information that is stored there after the user submits it. I am also using vue js 2 if that matters to anyone.

Comment: You are not using the variable `realBlogs` anywhere in the template. Is that intentional? Also did you try to debug if `realBlogs` is changing using the [vue dev tools extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vuejs-devtools/nhdogjmejiglipccpnnnanhbledajbpd).

Comment: In addition to Merhawi comment, note that instead to interact with the Firebase Realtime Database via the REST API, you could use the JS SDK which will make things much easier in case of more complex queries.